# Android Date Picker pre 1900

Tags: android, calendar, gregorian-calendar

Can a calendar date picker go back further than 1900 or even further than 1582 (the day the Gregorian calendar was introduced)?

If can can, can you show me some documenation where I can reproduce it going back further?

Comment: I think you'll need to create you own custom DatePicker/CalendarView as handling pre epoch time is not in standard Java. The good is that the source code for those widgets/views are available in the Android Open Source Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was quite simple really. In the XML you can set a min and max date.

Comment: What about adding some code to show how someone can do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me I use this code :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
DatePickerDialog picker;
final Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = cldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);
picker = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        //-- Do your stuff with the date picked : dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear + 1)+"/"+year
        }
    }, year, month, day);
//-- Set the calendar to the year one to year 3000 !
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
calendar.set(1, 0, 1);
picker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
calendar.set(3000, 0, 1);
picker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
///////////////////
picker.show();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Proposed solution didn't work for me. I used the following code:

> ```
>     void initDatePicker()
>     {
>         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
>         calendar.set(1, 0, 1);
>         datePicker.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
>         calendar.set(3000, 0, 1);
>         datePicker.setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
>     }
> ```